# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower' from Tfidf_vect.fit

Tags: python, vector, nlp, svm, tf-idf

I'm trying to apply SVM using tf-idf features .
but I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/lam/.PyCharm2019.1/config/scratches/scratch_1.py", line 35, in <module>
    Tfidf_vect.fit(data['input'])
  File "C:\Users\lam\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1631, in fit
    X = super().fit_transform(raw_documents)
  File "C:\Users\lam\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1058, in fit_transform
    self.fixed_vocabulary_)
  File "C:\Users\lam\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 970, in _count_vocab
    for feature in analyze(doc):
  File "C:\Users\lam\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 352, in <lambda>
    tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
  File "C:\Users\lam\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 256, in <lambda>
    return lambda x: strip_accents(x.lower())
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'
```

This is my code:

```
data['input']= [nltk.word_tokenize(entry) for entry in data['input']]

Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(data['input'],data['Class'],test_size=0.2)

Encoder = LabelEncoder()
Train_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Train_Y)
Test_Y = Encoder.fit_transform(Test_Y)

Tfidf_vect = TfidfVectorizer()
Tfidf_vect.fit(data['input'])


Train_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Train_X)
Test_X_Tfidf = Tfidf_vect.transform(Test_X)

print(Tfidf_vect.vocabulary_)
```

I'm using python 3.6.0, my dataset is in Arabic.

Thank you,,

Comment: Add `print(type(data['input']), type(data['Class']))` before `Train_X, Test_X, Train_Y, Test_Y = sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split(` and post the output.

Comment: This is the output: `<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>`

Comment: `data['input']` is a list of lists, and it seems `fit(something)` wants a list of strings, not a list of lists

Comment: hmm yes this is true, it is a list of lists. data['input'] is a column of sentences that I want to extract feature from. How can I do this ?

Comment: get the sublists out of lists of lists using indexes or a for loop

Comment: I solved it, I wrote `data['input'].list()` instead of `data['input']`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says that `TfidfVectorizer` expects a string as its input - not a list of string. It does all the tokenization by itself (but you can plug in a custom tokenizer within `TfidfVectorizer`, if you want).

So I would try a simpler pipeline, without the first line (with `nltk.tokenize..`). But I cannot be 100% sure, because you did not provide any examples of actual input data that causes the error.

Comment: Is it wrong to write `Tfidf_vect.fit(data['input'].tolist())` ? it worked with me. Also I removed the first line

Comment: It is not wrong, but `TfidfVectorizer` should work equivalently with an original pandas.Series and with a list that consists of the same items. If it does not, it is at least strange.

Comment: I removed the first line and used `Tfidf_vect.fit(data['input'])` and it worked! Thank you..